# Как выйти из программы при определенном условии?

Tags: c++

Есть условие, при его выполнении программа должна закрываться.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
exit(0); //Параметр - статус, который ловит хост. Если хост ничего не ловит, все равно что тут стоит.
```

Все закрывает и выходит.

Comment: Спасибо! то что нужно.

Comment: Слева галочка, чтобы принять ответ

Answer (score 0):

Нет команды `'exit('число');'` в C++:

> error: 'exit' was not declared in this scope
>   exit(0);      ^

Мера: я заменил `'exit(0);'` на `'return 0;'`, всё заработало.

Comment: Так что  я замененыл 'exit(0);' на 'return 0;'  е патом заработала праграма.

Comment: Вообще-то есть,  заголовочный файл `stdlib.h` или `cstdlib`

Comment: `return 0;` поможет только в `main()`.

Comment: stdlib.h работает но, я не знаю что такое cstdlib.